# Linux Azure App Service naked domain for https not working with nginx container

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I just realized that navigating to my application using just `https://example.com` is not working but other URLs are resolving correctly like so:

`http://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

`http://www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

`https://example.com` -> `ETIMEDOUT`

`http://www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

So a little bit about the application, it is a react web application running in a Linux App Service in Azure, where I am running a nginx container to serve the react application.

I am using Namecheap for my domain provider and these are the two related redirect DNS records I have for my domain:

[image]

And this is the TLS/SSL Settings for my azure app service I am redirecting to:

[image]

Now I believe this is the culprit, but I am not exactly sure what needs to happen here.  This is my nginx.conf in the nginx container:

```
http{
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        return 302 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
          expires -1;
          # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
        }

        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          expires 1y;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
        }

        # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `http://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com` works, i don't think your nginx conf is wrong. I see a warning in your screenshot, is it possible that you need to manually add the certificate for exmaple.com in there? I'm not familiar with azure and i'm no sure where the block happens. 99% when an `ETIMEDOUT` happens is firewalls at work, but that can't be, as `https://www.example.com` works.

Comment: Any update for this issue?